# SQL SUBMENU DELETE

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have MENU table(id,name,refparent)

When I delete one menu I want to delete all su submenus and submenus of its submenus.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      <Author,,Name>
-- Create date: <Create Date,,>
-- Description: <Description,,>
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[cms_menu_delete]
    @refUser bigint,
    @refPortal int,
    @refId bigint
AS
BEGIN
SET XACT_ABORT ON

BEGIN TRANSACTION


SELECT MENU.Id,MENU.[Order]
INTO #MENUSAMELEVEL
FROM MENU
WHERE MENU.refParent=(SELECT MENU.refParent FROM MENU WHERE MENU.Id=@refId)

SELECT MENU.Id
INTO #MENUSUBS
FROM MENU
WHERE MENU.refParent=@refId

DELETE FROM MENU WHERE Id = @refId


COMMIT TRANSACTION

SELECT 'SUCCEED' as Result 

END
```

I took submenus to #MENUSUBSbut it is not enough to delete them. They also can have submenus. How can I do it
[image]

picture above if I delete green ,orange ones wşll be also deleted.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Ever heard of `Recursive CTE's`. Can you add sample data and expected result ?

Answer (score 0):

**Variant 1.** - `dml trigger`

```
      CREATE TRIGGER cascade_delete_menu
      ON MENU 
      FOR DELETE
      AS
      DELETE FROM MENU WHERE Id IN (SELECT refParent FROM deleted WHERE refParent is not null)
```

**Variant 2.** `recursive CTE` - Docs https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx

select all ids include leafs -> delete all ids